# why toolbar text color always white in SwiftUI project

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a problem in my  SwiftUI project. In toolbar text buttons color is white, even I add this code

```
init() {
        UIToolbar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red
    }
```

there is not any change, I do not know why? Any idea?

[image]

Comment: It is not white! you are in dark mode! :)

Comment: how can I change it

Comment: command + shift + A, or on iPhone setting dark mode or light mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set an accent color to the view like this:

```
.accentColor(Color.red)
```